# Rotate plane in 3d array/list

Tags: python, geometry

I have got a 2d list of (x,y,z) coordinates. Now I would like to rotate everything by `a` degrees around a vertical line going through the mid point. All points should retain the same y-coordinates. Both plains will be vertical. There is [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375995/rotate-3d-plane), but I cant understand a word and I have looked into the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)). Here is a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rotation around the y-axis can be expressed through [the following matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions):

```
    ┌                     ┐
    │ cos(α)   0   sin(α) │
R = │    0     1     0    │
    │ -sin(α)  0   cos(α) │
    └                     ┘
```

where α denotes the rotation angle.

We can thus rotate around the mid point by first translating by the negated mid-point vector, applying R, and translating back:

```
def rotate_points(points, alpha):
    # compute the mid point
    midpoint = np.mean(points, 0)

    # let's ignore the y coordinate
    midpoint[1] = 0.0

    # translate all points so that midpoint is at [0, y, 0]
    translated = points - midpoint

    # for use in the following step
    cos = np.cos(alpha)
    sin = np.sin(alpha)

    # apply the rotation matrix
    rotated = [np.array([v[0] * cos + v[2] * sin, v[1], -v[0] * sin + v[2] * cos])
               for v in translated]

    # translate back
    untranslated = rotated + midpoint

    # ...and done
    return untranslated
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the future, I used this function to get the new point coordinates for every point on the vertical line on the edge and connected them with a line drawing algo.

```
def thirdPoint(p1, p2, a):
    x1, y, z1 = p1
    x2, _, z2 = p2
    
    aP1P2 = math.atan2(z2-z1, x2-x1)  # In radians, not degrees
    aP1P3 = aP1P2 - math.radians(a)

    x3 = x1 + rDis * math.cos(aP1P3)
    z3 = z1 + rDis * math.sin(aP1P3)
    
    return (x3, y1, z3)
```